# Does the assert statement swallows exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, assert

I have the following test:

```
@Test
public void testValues() {
    User user = new User();

//  user.getCode().equals("CODE");
    assert user.getCode().equals("CODE");
}
```

Expected behavior for this test would be to fail, because `getCode` was not yet initialized and therefore evaluates to `null`. I would expect a `NullPointerException` to be thrown. But that does not happen, but instead the test passes.

Uncommenting the line, the test fails as expected with a `NullPointerException`.

So is here my conception false, or is something going wrong?

I run the test with the eclipse JUnit plug-in. I also have the -ea option enabled under `Windows → Preferences → Java → JUnit`, so assertions should be enabled.

Comment: A failed assertion throws `AssertionError`. Throwing an unexpected throwable is not exactly the same thing as passing.

Comment: Why are you using Java assert instead of JUnit Assert?  I prefer the latter.  JUnit lets you test for exceptions being thrown with its @expected attribute.

Comment: The problem with java assertions is that they are optionally checked; [enable them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable). Disabled they are not executed. And here JUnit assertions should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, assert does not swallow exceptions. How do you run the tests? Perhaps assertions are disabled in you r run.
I ran your test on Intellij Idea and received an exception.

I suggest you use org.easytesting.fest-assert. This allows you to write assertions like this:

```
    assertThat(user.getCode()).isEqualTo("CODE");
```

or more complex stuff like:

```
    assertThat(user.getCode()).containsIgnoringCase("CODE");
```

This way when the assertion fails you also get a more detailed exception.

Comment: I'm running it, using JUnit plug-in for eclipse. And the -ea option is enabled.

Comment: Can you try to run an assertion that should fail, to see if assertions work in your run? For example: assert 1 == 2

Comment: So this was some strange quirk from eclipse. I precautionally deleted all old runconfigurations, but still the same. Had to restart eclipse. Now it is working as expected.

Comment: I accepted your answer, because as far as I can tell, you was the first who really addressed the question.

Answer (score 3):

When making JUnit tests, you are expected to use [JUnit assertions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html). The built-in `assert` is a different thing. Try something like this to see what happens.

```
@Test
public void testValues() {
    User user = new User();

    Assert.assertEquals(user.getCode(), "CODE");
}
```

You will see that the test fails. Your previous code wasn't throwing, most likely because the JVM didn't have assertions enabled (the -ea flag). By default, the Java Virtual Machine will ignore all `assert`s. That is something you can test as well: running the same code you have in your question with `-ea`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've forgotten to enable assertions at runtime (the `-ea` option to the `java` tool, or somewhere in your runtime config if running through an IDE). If assertions are not enabled, the entire expression is completely ignroed (not executed), so you don't get an NPE.

For example, with this code:

```
class Temp {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Testing");
        (new Temp()).testValues(null);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    public void testValues(String str) {

        assert str.equals("CODE");
    }
}
```

If I run it without assertions enabled, naturally no exception occurs because `str.equals("CODE")` is never evaluated.

But if I run it with assertions enabled, I get an NPE as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `assert` for Junit test. Use `assertEquals` and such.

1. Java assertion are only enabled when using the `-ea` `java` option.
2. Junit assertions will throw you a nice message for certain type (like `assertEquals("Foobar", "f00bar");`)
3. `assert` will ignore exception if not enabled because the associated code will not be executed (ignored), but you'll have to "throw" any checked exception.